# Gmdate() is always 10 minutes off actual GMT time

Tags: php, laravel

Something really weird is happening where the function `gmtdate()` returns the wrong time. It's always 10 minutes less.

```
$utc_str        = gmdate( 'd-m-Y:H-i', time() );
print("Time: " . $utc_str . "\n\n");
```

*Note: I am not comparing the gmdate to my time (that would have a timezone bias). I am comparing it to the GMT time (I just google `gmt time` and check that).

So examples of what I get is `Time: 17-03-2017:00-19` when the actual time is `00-29`. It's always 10 minutes off. Is this something to do with my PHP setup?

My PHP.ini file has `date.timezone = UTC`.  I am running Laravel inside Homestead (vagrant). This is on my local Windows 10 laptop. The Windows 10 OS time is correct. Not sure about the Homestead VM

Comment: Probably means that your server time isn't correct

Comment: @RyanVincent I am running Laravel inside Homestead (vagrant). This is on my local Windows 10 laptop. The Windows 10 OS time is correct. Not sure about the  Homestead VM.

Comment: try setting the `time` in your homestead using the command `date +%T -s "HH:MM:SS"` make sure you replace `HH:MM:SS` with your local time

Comment: Do you have ntp daemon running on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Homestead server has time drift issue. You should consider to use ntp client inside the VM to sync time with time servers.

The issue is still on their issue tracker: 
https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/463

If you're not using Homestead in production / long run, using [ntpdate](http://man.cx/ntpdate(1)) once will do the job:

```
 ntpdate [time server domain name]
```